# How to check wsusoffline

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, wsus

Since standard Windows updates were stuck on a laptop (Windows 7 64-bit), I used [wsusoffline](http://download.wsusoffline.net/).

After some hours, all seems OK. From the install log of wsusoffline I can read lines like

```
27/05/2017 19:30:21,72 - Info: Installed ..\w61-x64\glb\windows6.1-kb2840631-x64_022ec000034f19b7ce059c0f5175bb921b53badc.cab
```

But the point is that I can't see the knowledge base references (for example, `kb2840631`) in the control panel history.

Is that normal? How can I double check it has been installed indeed?

Comment: Those installs actually apply to the image, I don't think the active system is affected. And if it is, then you'd only know by not having it presented to you in the normal update mechanism.

Comment: Hopefully, the active system *is* affected: indeed I see the patches in the installed updates, as per my comment [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1213638/how-to-check-wsusoffline#comment1771439_1213644)

Answer (score 6):

#### How can I double check it has been installed indeed?

You can use the following command to list all of the installed updates:

> wmic qfe list brief /format:texttablewsys > "%USERPROFILE%\hotfix.txt"

- QFE                 - Quick Fix Engineering (patches)
- Texttablewsys.xsl   - Optional style sheet for table format

Source [Quick and Easy Way to List All the Windows Updates Installed on Your System](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/quick-and-easy-way-list-all-windows-updates-installed-your-system.htm)

The output file will look something like this:

```
Description      FixComments  HotFixID   InstallDate  InstalledBy          InstalledOn  Name  ServicePackInEffect  Status  
Update                        KB2849697               Hal\DavidPostill     1/4/2015                                        
Update                        KB2849696               Hal\DavidPostill     1/4/2015                                        
Update                        KB2841134               Hal\DavidPostill     1/4/2015                                        
Update                        KB2670838               Hal\DavidPostill     1/4/2015                                        
Update                        KB971033                Hal\DavidPostill     1/4/2015                                        
Update                        KB3134760               Hal\DavidPostill     6/3/2016                                        
...
```

Use - [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to search the output file for a particular update that you are interested in:

```
> find "KB971033" hotfix.txt

---------- HOTFIX.TXT
Update                        KB971033                Hal\DavidPostill     1/4/2015
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: a quick clarification: do you expect that the result of this can be different from what is shown in Windows Update History? Thank you

Comment: @Giulio No idea - I haven't checked.

Comment: Well, the results match the *installed updates*, while the *update history* is either somehow corrupted or it simply doesn't show the detailed kb patches (by design). Anyway your answer has been helpful to lead me in the right direction.